# English equivalent for "Just eat the cake. Why count the holes?"

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests

In Malayalam/Indian, there's an expression:

> Appam thinnal pore, kuzhi ennano!

It literally translates to:

> Just eat the [appam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appam) (Indian pancake). Why count the holes!

It implies that one should just enjoy the final product and need not bother how it originated.

It is usually said by an impatient person when asked too many questions about his product or method.

What could be an equivalent expression in English?

Comment: The ends justify the means?

Comment: @JackGraveney it's not about justifying one's actions.

Comment: Just eat the chapati and not ask why there so many bumps.

Comment: “Here. “<hands over some indescribable food stuff>  “Don’t ask. Just eat it.”

Comment: I don't understand the idiom! Where are the holes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although it emphasizes *gifting* or *offering* perhaps more than the idiom about the holey pancake, 'not look a gift horse in the mouth' is very similar both in use and in intent:

> if someone tells you *not to look a gift horse in the mouth*, they mean that **you should not criticize or feel doubt about something good that has been offered to you**

[look a gift horse in the mouth. (n.d.) Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.. (2006). Retrieved February 12 2016 from http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+a+gift+horse+in+the+mouth Emphasis mine.]

Answer (score 8):

***Don't ask how the sausage is made.***

This phrase stems from the fact that sausage is often made from the less desirable parts of an animal. Even though it may taste delicious, you may not want to think about putting a tube of pig anus in your mouth. Just enjoy the finished product, and don't dwell too much on its origins.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on context, consider:

***Beggars can't be choosers***

> *Prov.* If someone gives you something you asked for, you should not complain about what you get. [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beggars+can't+be+choosers)

***Take it or leave it***

> *Inf.* Take this one or none; you have no choice [FOD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Take+it+or+leave+it)

Comment: A bit extreme, but I like it. :)

Answer (score 0):

*"The ends justify the means."* - This is dark, and generally considered negative, but it basically means if the final result is good, it doesn't matter how you got there.

*"You can't make an omelet without breaking a few eggs."* - Again, somewhat negative it tone, but keeps the food reference.